# Javascript not working and disappearing on refresh

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a Tic Tac Toe game, but i have a problem with the javascript part of it- the script doesn't work, and when i refresh the page and check in Firebug- it has disappeared entirely- Firebug says no script on page. I am trying to make the image with the appropriate symbol- O or X- to appear on the screen when clicked on, but all i have is failure at this point. Here is the HTML:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheet1.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Script1.js"></script> 
</head>
   <body>
      <div id="grid">
          <div id="oneOne">
          <a id="buttonShow" href="#"><img src="Pictures/oSymbol.png" id="theImage" />
          <img src="Pictures/xSymbol.png" /></a>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
img {
position:absolute;
margin:0px;
top: 3px;
left: 3px;
}
#theImage {
visibility:hidden;
}
```

And the Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    document.getElementById("buttonShow").onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById("theImage").style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you forget to include jquery into the html?

Comment: No, I didn't. Thank you very much! But I can't choose your answer as best now, there's no tick next to it.